# Polymer 1.x: accessing element within dom-if

Tags: polymer, dom-if

[Here is my JSBin](http://jsbin.com/forudojoza/edit?html,console,output)

Click on the "First Name: James" text.

I have an input element within dom-if. In an event, I am making dom-if to pass and so the element will come into existence but I cannot access the input element immediately after making the dom-if condition pass.

May be I need to know when the dom-if is actually evaluated and why the element does not exist even if the condition has become true.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-form/iron-form.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style></style>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{!editMode}}">
    <span id="name" on-tap="_makeEditable">{{name}}: {{value}}</div>
  </template>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{editMode}}">
    <paper-input id="input" label="{{name}}" value="{{value}}"></paper-input>
  </template>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
        editMode: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        },
        name: {
          type:String,
          value:"First Name"
        },
        value: {
          type:String,
          value:"James"
        }
      },
      _makeEditable: function() {
        this.editMode = true;
        //how to find the input element here
        //this.$$('#input').querySelector("input").focus();
        //this.$.input.querySelector("input").focus();
      }
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because setting `this.editMode` to `true` does not update the DOM instantaneously.

You should be running your selector asynchronously, so that Polymer has some time to update the DOM, such as:

```
this.async(function() {
   this.$$('#input').focus();
})
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsbin.com/lupijihoje/1/edit?html,console,output).

Comment: Thanks @Yurii! That worked. <br/> Although I am facing another issue, `this.$$('#input').focus()` does not work for me. It works when I do `this.$$('#input').querySelector('input').focus()`. It works fine in the JSBin which is a simpler version of what I am actually doing. Any hints on where I should look at for this?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: As I said, @Yurii, it works fine in JSBin, only in my local machine it is a problem. Probably a bug in the polymer version I am using (v1.6)!? Do you know how I can refer to an exact version of polymer in the JSBin? I am quite new to this. Thanks...